# How can I position elements below a WebView inside a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-linearlayout

I tried to create a fragment with a `WebView` which had a `Button` above and below it. The button above was displayed, but the one below is not shown. It's like the `WebView` is trying to take up all the rest of the space on the screen, regardless of what other elements might be in the `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I show things that are underneath the `WebView` and stop the `WebView` from occupying all the rest of the space in the view?

---

When trying to add weights, things got even more weird. Giving the buttons a weight of 1 and the `WebView` a weight of 0, meant the buttons didn't show at all:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then finally when trying to give the `WebView` a weight of 0.1, the buttons did both show but they had a height of only around 2dp on the screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2.1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your WebView's height is `match_parent` in all of these, so it's the size of its container. That means even without the buttons it would fill the available space - with a button above, the WebView will be pushed down and you won't be able to see the bottom of it. And the button below is even further off the screen. You need to set the height as `0dp` when using the weight - see the examples here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/linear

Comment: @cactustictacs I tried all these with height `0dp` as well but it still didn't work. the reason I was using `match_parent` was I thought it would use all the space of the parent apart from the space used by other views

Comment: Nah, `match_parent` literally means "whatever the parent's size is, match that" - it's meant for filling a container on one or both axes. Any adaptive stuff that fills the available space requires a size of `0dp`, and then whatever your attributes your containing `ViewGroup` uses to decide how that resizing should happen. So for a `LinearLayout` you use `layout_weight` (available space will be shared depending on the proportions of those weights), for a `ConstraintLayout` it'll depend on the constraints you've set, etc. It's always `0dp` though, which is treated like "not explicitly specified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` so that your `webview` takes up all the free space between the buttons in height:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="test2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks - that works, but I have no idea why. I thought that giving a higher weight to a view will make it have more priority when allocating space. but here I want the `WebView` to have less space than the default, not more.

Comment: The `weight` shows in what proportion you place your views if you didn't set a static value. So by setting a `weight` on a view with a `height` of `0dp`, that view will take up all the free space not occupied by other views with a static `height`. If instead of a `webview` you had 2 views with a `height` of `0dp` and a `weight` of `1`, then they would take up the entire free height in a ratio of 50:50